# How to construct a path using jmespath to get values

Tags: python, json, jmespath

I am having problems getting some values using `jmespath.search()`.

Just to put it in context, I am downloading all the information from my request in a CSV file. I then upload this as a JSON and using JMESPath, I wish to get the values.

I want to get the `#value` where `'_instrumentIdScheme': 'mhi:MHILIST'`

json fixed:

```
[
    {
        "_fpmlVersion": "5-6",
        "header": {
            "messageType": "PrevDayCloseBond",
            "sendTo": [
                {
                    "#value": "Anvil"
                }
            ],
            "creationTimestamp": "2021-09-28T06:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "m:asOfDate": {
            "#value": "2021-09-28T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "_xmlns": "http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting",
        "_xmlns:m": "urn:com.mizuho.bdm",
        "_xmlns:mhi": "urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi",
        "_xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
        "_xsi:schemaLocation": "http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/fpml-5-6-reporting.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/mizuho-fpml.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/mhi/fpml/mhi-fpml.xsd",
        "m:assetPricing": [
            {
                "m:pricingSource": [
                    {
                        "#value": "LON-XEN-BBG"
                    },
                    {
                        "#value": "BGN",
                        "_pricingSourceScheme": "mizuho:bloomberg-source"
                    }
                ],
                "m:instrumentId": [
                    {
                        "#value": "100001380992",
                        "_instrumentIdScheme": "mhi:MHILIST"
                    },
                    {
                        "#value": "100001380992",
                        "_instrumentIdScheme": "mhsa:instrument-id"
                    }
                ],
                "m:currency": {
                    "#value": "USD"
                },
                "m:price": [
                    {
                        "value": 140.78125,
                        "measureType": {
                            "#value": "Bid Price",
                            "_assetMeasureScheme": "mizuho:price-type"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 140.875,
                        "measureType": {
                            "#value": "Mid Price",
                            "_assetMeasureScheme": "mizuho:price-type"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 140.96875,
                        "measureType": {
                            "#value": "Offer Price",
                            "_assetMeasureScheme": "mizuho:price-type"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "m:pricingDate": "2021-09-28T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: from your sample i dont arrive to have a json correct..

Comment: This is a part of my json... I didn't want to put all of it because it's too big.

Comment: JSON requires double quotes for its strings, its the reason the json is not good

Comment: i dont see your json..even better your csv

Comment: sorry but your json is not good... check with site online

Comment: You should consider re-editing your JSON in the question, without it, it looks like @Frenchy completely made it up to answer you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. replace all simple quotes by double quotes
2. to select all #value with the condition:

---

```
def flatten(container):
    for i in container:
        if isinstance(i, (list,tuple)):
            for j in flatten(i):
                yield j
        else:
            yield i


str = """
[
    {
        "_fpmlVersion": "5-6",
        "header": {
            "messageType": "PrevDayCloseBond",
            "sendTo": [
                {
                    "#value": "Anvil"
                }
            ],
            "creationTimestamp": "2021-09-28T06:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "m:asOfDate": {
            "#value": "2021-09-28T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "_xmlns": "http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting",
        "_xmlns:m": "urn:com.mizuho.bdm",
        "_xmlns:mhi": "urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi",
        "_xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
        "_xsi:schemaLocation": "http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/fpml-5-6-reporting.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/fpml/mizuho-fpml.xsd urn:com.mizuho.bdm.mhi http://svc-bdmentity01p:8080/schema/7.2.0/com/mizuho/bdm/mhi/fpml/mhi-fpml.xsd",
        "m:assetPricing": [
            {
                "m:pricingSource": [
                    {
                        "#value": "LON-XEN-BBG"
                    },
                    {
                        "#value": "BGN",
                        "_pricingSourceScheme": "mizuho:bloomberg-source"
                    }
                ],
                "m:instrumentId": [
                    {
                        "#value": "100001380992",
                        "_instrumentIdScheme": "mhi:MHILIST"
                    },
                    {
                        "#value": "100001380992",
                        "_instrumentIdScheme": "mhsa:instrument-id"
                    }
                ],
                "m:currency": {
                    "#value": "USD"
                },
                "m:price": [
                    {
                        "value": 140.78125,
                        "measureType": {
                            "#value": "Bid Price",
                            "_assetMeasureScheme": "mizuho:price-type"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 140.875,
                        "measureType": {
                            "#value": "Mid Price",
                            "_assetMeasureScheme": "mizuho:price-type"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 140.96875,
                        "measureType": {
                            "#value": "Offer Price",
                            "_assetMeasureScheme": "mizuho:price-type"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "m:pricingDate": "2021-09-28T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
"""
str = str.replace("\n", "").replace("\t", "")
str = json.loads(str)   
#print(str)

valueslist = jmespath.search('[]["m:assetPricing"][][]."m:instrumentId"[?"_instrumentIdScheme" == `mhi:MHILIST`].["#value"]', str)   
#print(valueslist)

values = list(flatten(valueslist))
print(values)
```

---

result:

```
['100001380992']
```

Comment: Hi @Frenchy, thanks for your reply. But I am getting this, follow your steps: [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

Comment: I will update my question so you can see how I am doing this.

Comment: i have built my answer following your json....

Comment: @BrunoLorena your problem is in the loop.. with the json fixed, i have the same result. i have fixed my flatten list, there is a little problem..

Comment: Thanks @Frenchy with this solution you provided me, I was able to get all the values.